# Can't add board for RFDuino in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide

I tried to upload sketch to my RFDuino. I can select the RFDuino port. But I can't upload cos I can't select the RFDuino board.

I followed the installation steps listed [here](https://github.com/RFduino/RFduino)
but I don't see RFduino package in Board Manager after I finished the steps above.

I am using Mac Mojave and Arduino IDE v1.8.9. I have tried it with v1.6.6 but results the same.

Comment: I get `Error downloading http://rfduino.com/package_rfduino166_index.json`

Comment: the company RFDigital is gone. no support. try a manual install

Comment: I had this problem with STM32 package. Go to Arduino15 folder(%appdata%) and delete download cache

Comment: @SilvioCro, did you try it?

Comment: @Juraj When I did those steps(in my case it was STM32 package - [this link](http://dan.drown.org/stm32duino/package_STM32duino_index.json), it worked. Go `AppData\Local\Arduino15` and delete `package_index.json.sig` and `package_index.json` files

Comment: @Juraj No. Sorry, I was on the phone(when I wrote 1st comment) so it was messy. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that rfduino.com's domain is gone, so the link will always return with an error downloading. After reading this thread [arduino.cc](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=610331.0), @pert posted [a link for the .json file](https://gist.github.com/per1234/f7822073e05276c4243740eaab4235d1/raw/9c34051294ddd54dbbdf3bec392df0afef8da938/package_rfduino166_index.json) that used to be at the website you have. I used this link on MacOS Mojave and Arduino v1.8.9 and it worked perfectly!